# PHP preg_replace all occurrences for tags

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have this:

```
$tagName = "id";
$value = "ID12345";
$text = "<%id%> some text <%id%> something";
$a = new A();
echo $a->replaceAllTags($tagName, $value, $text);
```

and I want to create this:

```
"ID12345 some text ID12345 something"
```

Tried this and didn't work:

```
private function replaceAllTags($tagName, $value, $text)
{
    $pattern = "/<%" . $tagName . "%>/";
    while (preg_match($pattern, $text)) {
        $text = preg_replace($pattern, $value, $text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

This didn't work too:

```
private function replaceAllTags($tagName, $value, $text)
{
    $pattern = "/<%(" . $tagName . ")%>/";
    $text = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 
        function($m) {
           return $value;
    }, $text);
    return $text;
}
```

EDITED:
**Problem was that I wrote a PHPUnit test and had <%id> instead of <%id%>.**

P.s.: private should be public

Comment: I don't see the need for a regex here ... is there a reason you are not using the easier and faster `str_replace()` function?

Comment: "If you don't need fancy replacing rules (like regular expressions), you should always use this function instead of preg_replace()."   http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that a regex is not really needed for that, it seems to me the problem is with the "private" visibility. A method which you want to access from the outside needs the "public" visibility.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 1):

1. Your method A::replaceAllTags declared as a private instead of public. Details [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)
2. If you want use regexp - try this snippet.

   ```
   class A { 
        public function replaceAllTags($tagName, $value, $text) {
            $pattern = "/<%(" . $tagName . ")%>/";
            $text = preg_replace($pattern, $value, $text);
            return $text;    
        }    
    }
   ```

I advise you to use simple [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). Like this:

```
public function replaceAllTags($tagName, $value, $text) {
    $pattern = "<%" . $tagName . "%>";
    $text = str_replace($pattern, $value, $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) instead.

```
private function replaceAllTags($tagName, $value, $text)
{
    $pattern = "<%" . $tagName . "%>";
    $text = str_replace($pattern, $value, $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked fine for me try it :

```
<?php
     function replaceAllTags($tagName, $value, $text)
    {
        $pattern = "/(<%)(" . $tagName . ")(%>)/";
        while (preg_match($pattern, $text)) {
            $text = preg_replace($pattern, $value, $text);
        }
        return $text;
    }
    $tagName = "id";
    $value = "ID12345";
    $text = "<%id%> some text <%id%> something";

    echo replaceAllTags($tagName, $value, $text);
?>
```

the result was : **ID12345 some text ID12345 something**

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with any of the functions! Just keep in mind that your functions are private functions and can only be accessed withing that class!